# addAttributeToFilter with OR and BETWEEN

Tags: collection, filter

I'm adding a couple of filters with `addAttributeToFilter`. I have the fields "year", "year_from", "year_to". I either want to match the year exactly to the "year" attribute or make a "between" by using "year_from" and "year_to". I know how to use `addAttributeToFilter` to make "OR" conditions. However 
I don't know how to make an "OR" filter with a grouped "AND", something like `year = 1999 OR (year_from <= 1999 AND year_to >= 1999)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as -

```
$filter_a = array('eq'=>'1999');
$filter_b = array('from'=>'1999','to'=>'1999');

addFieldToFilter('year',array( $filter_a, $filter_b));
```

Comment: The from/to filter is not applied to the same attribute but to different ones - year_from, year_to. This is because the vendors provide different information for different products - sometimes a specific year, sometimes a year range with a from and to. But it's good to know that I can combine multiple arrays of filters like this. I will try experimenting with that.

Answer (score 3):

This code is not relevant to the source snippet you have provided. But for the sake of using `OR` condition to filter collections you can use this.

```
// Get all event statuses.
            $allowedStatus = array(
                                    array("finset" => array('Running')),
                                    array("finset" => array('Expired')),
                                    array("finset" => array('Not Active')),
                                    array("finset" => array('Test')),
                                  );

            // Filter by event status.
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter("event_status", $allowedStatus); // This will filter objects which contains any one of the above statuses.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter your result with the following set of example code

```
$collection =Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load();
    $collection->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('attribute1');  
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('attribute2');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('attribute3');        
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'attribute1', 'finset'=>value1),
                            array('attribute'=>'attribute2', 'finset'=>value2),
                            array('attribute'=>'attribute3', 'finset'=>value3)
    ));
```